# Google App Engine : Select from the artifact list by supplying the number: What does the number mean?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

### What i am doing

1. I am trying to use the google app engine for the first time
2. I have installed JAVA & Maven as specified by docs

[***LINK I AM REFERING: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating***][1]

---

### I am trying to run:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.17 -Dapplication-id=XXXXXX -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:
```

**Application-id**: I got from the google console

**Doc says ::**
Select from the artifact list by supplying the number corresponding to

```
com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype.
```

---

### Questions

1. What does it mean  by "number"?
2. Where can we get that number ?
3. Confused on this part !

---

Answer (score 0):

When you run archetype:generate, it spits out a long list of available archetypes. Each is given a number (which varies over time as more are added). You're expected to find the one that corresponds to the desired archetype and enter it in the console. In this case, you're being instructed to find the one matching the tutorial you're running.

To understand this better, just run `mvn archetype:generate` and look at the output, you can always quit without selecting anything.